# MacBook Pro: no external monitor works

Tags: mac, hdmi, macbook, vga, thunderbolt

I have a 2011 early model MacBook Pro (High Sierra 10.13.3) with a Thunderbolt port being the only way of connecting an external monitor. I use a Mini DisplayPort-HDMI adaptor to connect my LG IPS236 monitor. It worked great until I updated to Sierra, then it stopped workin. SMC was reset, everything was reset, I tried different monitors, tried different adaptors (Mini DisplayPort-VGA), different cables, nothing.

If I connect the monitor with the HDMI adaptor, the MacBook screen flashes black, than nothing happens. If I connect with the VGA adaptor, then there is no flash.

Tried reinstalling High Sierra, tried al the resets, spent hours on the phone with Support, nothing. I am suspecting the HDMI port might be faulty, but I don't know how to test it.

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Get hold of the original OS version that the computer came with - you may have a USB or set of CD's with the mac. Using an external HDD, install the older OS to the external HDD. Try testing from a blank, new OSX version that you have installed to the external drive. Boot to this drive by holding down ALT/OPT at startup. Before testing make sure that you update OSX first before any testing.